# neo4j apoc.path.expandConfig - How to use relationshipFilter with a list of relationships

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

According to the documentations, the pipe char (|) acts as a `or` in the relationshipFilter, while the comma char (,) acts as a concatenation of relationships, creating a list of them.

see for [example](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/graph-querying/expand-subgraph-nodes/) (look at the explanation with the black background comparing to the query itself):
[image]

and:

[here, page 14: sequences](https://prezi.com/p/owhz2icrbmby/apoc-path-expander-procedures/):
[image]

The question is, are commas stronger than pipes?
i.e., If I want several options of steps sequences, can I specify several strict lists, or do I must specify one list, each step with several options?

I wanted to achieve 4 relationship sequence options:

1.CREATE> or

2.REACT,REPLY or

3.CREATE>,RELATED or

4.REPLY>,CREATE

So I wrote a simple query:

```
MATCH(u:User{key:1})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(u, {maxLevel: 3,
relationshipFilter: 'CREATE>|REACT,REPLY|CREATE>,RELATED|REPLY>,CREATE',
uniqueness:"RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL"})
YIELD path
RETURN path
```

Given a sample data:

```
MERGE (a:User{key: 1})
MERGE (b:Tags{key: 2})
MERGE (c:Post{key: 3})
MERGE (d:Comment{key: 4})
MERGE (e:Comment{key: 5})
MERGE (f:Comment{key: 6})
MERGE (g:User{key: 7})
MERGE (h:User{key: 8})
MERGE (i:Post{key: 9})
MERGE (j:Tags{key: 10})
MERGE (k:Post{key: 11})
MERGE (l:Comment{key: 12})


MERGE (a)-[:CREATE]-(b)
MERGE (a)-[:CREATE]-(c)
MERGE (a)-[:REACT]-(c)
MERGE (a)-[:CREATE]-(d)
MERGE (a)-[:REACT]-(d)
MERGE (b)-[:RELATED]-(c)
MERGE (d)-[:REPLY]-(c)
MERGE (d)-[:REPLY]-(d)
MERGE (h)-[:REACT]-(c)
MERGE (g)-[:REACT]-(c)
MERGE (h)-[:CREATE]-(j)
MERGE (j)-[:RELATED]-(c)
MERGE (g)-[:CREATE]-(i)
MERGE (e)-[:REPLY]-(i)
MERGE (f)-[:REPLY]-(i)
MERGE (a)-[:REPLY]-(i)
MERGE (h)-[:CREATE]-(k)
MERGE (l)-[:REPLY]-(k)
MERGE (a)-[:REACT]-(l)
```

I was expecting to get an answer including  `(a:User{key: 1})-[:REPLY]->(i:Post{key: 9})<-[:CREATE]-(g:User{key: 7})`, which corresponds with my last part of the `relationshipFilter`, but did not get it.

Thank you for your time

Comment: When I run this I don't see (g:User {key:7}) in my results at all. 

(Separately, there's a missing opening single quote after "relationshipFilter:")

Comment: Thank you for identifying the missing quote, that was a pasting error. The question remains, why can't I get the paths to (g:User {key:7}), while the query should support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your relationshipFilter needs to be changed.

You have written: `'CREATE>|REACT,REPLY|CREATE>,RELATED|REPLY>,CREATE'`
Which matches:

1. CREATE> OR REACT
2. REPLY OR CREATE
3. RELATED OR REPLY
4. CREATE (this clause is never checked because of maxLevel:3.)

It appears you intended to use the relationshipFilter: `"CREATE>,REACT|REPLY,CREATE>|RELATED,REPLY>|CREATE"`

Which matches

1. CREATE>
2. REACT OR REPLY
3. CREATE> OR RELATED
4. REPLY> OR CREATE

Comment: From my experimenting, it seems that once all the relationship filters have been cycled through, it starts again with the first filter. So "CREATE, REACT" will find sequences that alternate between CREATE and REACT.

Comment: According to the docs it is: 1. CREATE> 2.REACT,REPLY 3.CREATE>,RELATED 4.REPLY>,CREATE

Comment: See https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.expandConfig/#path-expander-paths-config-config-uniqueness

Comment: Where does it say that in the docs?


Your clause is "CREATE>|REACT,REPLY|CREATE>,RELATED|REPLY>,CREATE" which means 1. CREATE> OR REACT 2. REPLY OR CREATE> 3. RELATED OR REPLY> 4. CREATE.


If you want 1. CREATE> 2. REACT OR REPLY 3. CREATE> OR RELATED 4. REPLY> OR CREATE you need "CREATE>,REACT|REPLY,CREATE>|RELATED,REPLY>|CREATE". This version will find a path to (g).

Comment: I updated the question with the documentation. It is working as you said, but not as the docs say. Please update your answer accordingly and I will accept it. In the meanwhile I voted for it.

Comment: Done. Thanks for posting the documentation snippets, but I still can't see how they're incorrect. That said, I didn't understand the documentation until after I had experimented with the function... so they could be clearer. Maybe I'll submit a fix through the Edit button.

Comment: Question is, are pipes stronger than commas, or vise-versa :) I see now that pipes are weaker than commas, but when I read the documentation this is not clear...

Comment: I wanted to achieve 4 options of 2 hops, but got 4 hops, each with 2 options

Comment: Now that I finally understand the problem and the solution, updated the question again. You may want to consider to update the answer as well